# Can connect from PHP but not from Linux Redhat console

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

I'm trying to get access to my mysql DB from linux RedHat console. All the tome I'm getting:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Obviously it seems that the root password is incorrect, but it isn't, because I can connect without no problems from the Website. All the PHP configuration files from several installed frameworks are using the same configuration parameters.

I'm using the following to connect from console:

mysql -u root -p

When the console prompts the password I can't get access.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance.

Jordi

Comment: it really sounds like the password is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you try resetting the password for root@localhost? Might be fastest way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

check if php connects from the same machine/ip and if mysql binds address 0.0.0.0.

[dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/…](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) : *For example, if you bind to 0.0.0.0, you can connect to the server using all existing accounts. But if you bind to 127.0.0.1, the server accepts connections only on that address. In this case, first make sure that the 'root'@'127.0.0.1' account is present in the mysql.user table so that you can still*